# CASE WHEN to RETURN maximum edge property in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find out how to use a condition in a query. Basically, in the relationship between teachers and schools below, I need to get only teachers who moved from one school to another with a promotion. To do this, I use property (from 1 to 4, 1 is lowest role and 4 is highest) from [:HAD] in where statement, but the query brings up teacher were also promoted within the same school - has more than one [:HAD], which I don't need. So I am thinking to introduce an if statement who says if there are multiple [:HAD] between teacher and school, bring just the maximum [:HAD] property.

This is the original code which brings teachers who were promoted in the same school as well as those promoted to another school:

```
//CREATE LINK BETWEEN SCHOOLS FOR CENTRALITY MEASURE
//BASED ON TEACHERS MOVING TO ANOTHER SCHOOL BASED ON PROMOTION
MATCH (s1:School)<-[:WITH]-(:Contract)<-[x:HAD]-(:Teacher)-[y:HAD]->(:Contract)-[:WITH]->(s2:School)
WHERE y.HAD>x.HAD and s1 <> s2
MERGE (s1)-[:TRANSFER_ON_PROMOTION]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2
```

This is my alteration to the original code:

```
//CREATE LINK BETWEEN SCHOOLS FOR CENTRALITY MEASURE
//BASED ON TEACHERS MOVING TO ANOTHER SCHOOL BASED ON PROMOTION
MATCH (s1:School)<-[:WITH]-()<-[x:HAD]-(:Teacher)-[y:HAD]->()-[:WITH]->(s2:School)
WHERE y.HAD>x.HAD and s1 <> s2
RETURN toInteger(x.HAD) AS x,
CASE 
    WHEN (x ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1) > 1 THEN x
    ELSE 1
END as highest
MATCH (s1:School)<-[:WITH]-(:Contract)<-[x:HAD]-(:Teacher)-[y:HAD]->(:Contract)-[:WITH]->(s2:School)
WHERE y.HAD>highest and s1 <> s2
MERGE (s1)-[:TRANSFER_ON_PROMOTION]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`WITH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/) to chain queries and `max` to select the maximum HAD value:

```
MATCH (s1:School)<-[:WITH]-(:Contract)<-[x:HAD]-(:Teacher)-[y:HAD]->(:Contract)-[:WITH]->(s2:School)
WHERE s1 <> s2
WITH s1, max(x.HAD) AS xMaxHad, y, s2
WHERE y.HAD > xMaxHad
MERGE (s1)-[:TRANSFER_ON_PROMOTION]->(s2)
RETURN s1, s2
```

Note that modeling-wise, adding a `HAD` property to the `HAD` relationship seems bad practice - I'd recommend to use a different name for the property instead (e.g. `level` or `rank`). Even `HAD` is not a very good name, maybe `HELD` would be nicer.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I took note about the HAD property, will change that.